# "Could not determine ValueMapping for SqmExpression" Hibernate ConversionException with custom type for MonetaryAmount

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Update: Hibernate bug [HHH-17899](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17899) raised.

**Environment**: Spring Boot & Spring JPA 3.2.4, Hibernate 6.4.4, PostgreSQL.

I have a custom `MonetaryAmount` class, which internally wraps a `javax.money.MonetaryAmount` and a `BigDecimal`:

```
public class MonetaryAmount extends Number implements Comparable<MonetaryAmount> {
   ...
```

and I am using this as a JPA type, along with a `MonetaryAmountConverter` (which implements `AttributeConverter<MonetaryAmount, BigDecimal>`):

```
    @Convert(converter = MonetaryAmountConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "total_amount")
    private MonetaryAmount totalAmount = ZERO;

    @Convert(converter = MonetaryAmountConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "amount_raised")
    private MonetaryAmount amountRaised = ZERO;
```

The database columns in my Postgres database are of type `numeric(20,2)`.

When I'm writing Spring JPA queries, if I use a **mathematical operator** `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` between the two above fields on the LHS, and a single numeric literal on the RHS like so:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT l FROM Loan l where l.amountRaised + l.totalAmount >= 2 ")
```

then I get the following Hibernate exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.ConversionException: Could not determine ValueMapping for SqmExpression: org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmBinaryArithmetic@55bc8579
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.determineValueMapping(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:5872)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.lambda$visitComparisonPredicate$111(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:7524)
at app//org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitHqlNumericLiteral(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:5583)
...
```

So essentially it is not able to parse the numeric type on the RHS (even `2.0` and `2BD` do not work). **But here is the weird thing: if I include a second numeric literal term on the RHS, e.g. multiply the first numeric literal by 1, then it works fine**:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT l FROM Loan l where l.amountRaised + l.totalAmount >= 2 * 1")
```

Is this a Hibernate bug? Or do I need to change something in my custom class? You can find the test code here: https://github.com/sunildmonte/coffee.